# How to make a subcategory belong to a specific category in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a little problem with display subcategories belongs only in specific categories. For example: I have a categories: Business, Factory, Health ... and after I can add subcategories for example Own Company in category Business. In this case if I choose category Business I need to have only visible subcategories belongs to this category. How to make it?
This is my code.
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from slugify import slugify

class Kategoria(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name='Nazwa kategorii')
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='Adres SEO')

    class Meta: 
        verbose_name_plural = 'Kategorie'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Kategoria, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Subkategoria(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Kategoria', related_name='subkategoria', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Kategoria główna')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Subkategorie'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Strona(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Nazwa strony')
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='Adres SEO')
    www = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Adres strony', unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='Opis')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Kategoria', verbose_name='Kategoria', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('Subkategoria', verbose_name='Subkategoria', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Strony'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: What do you mean by "choose category Business"? Do you have any specific view you're talking about?

Comment: Business is a example. If I'll add the Post in the panel admin I gonna be have to choise a Category and Subcategory. And for example if I choose Category Business, in the next list I'll can choose only subcategories belongs to category Business

Comment: I'm going to describe what I think you want, please let me know where I'm wrong. You want to have 2 drop downs on the page, one for Category, and one for Subcategory. When the user selects a Category, the Subcategory drop down will then be filtered to only show Subcategories that are under that chosen Category, and you want this functionality to be present in the Django Admin. Is this correct?

Comment: Nathan exacly this I want:)